# What to do with an answer which is bad except for one line where it gives a good source?

Tags: discussion, answers

In [this answer](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/25260/6656) everything is bad, everything except for the last line which is a link to a good source is unrelated to the question. The first part is a rant against the NRA, and the second part is giving data that is not asked in the question with no context to connect it. My question is what to do with the one link of good data?

Editing the question to remove the bad parts and expanding an actual answer using the source looks like too radical a change for me. Also, taking that source and adding it to my answer with the proper data and quotes seems somewhat "plagiarismy".

What is the correct course of action?

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion there's nothing wrong with reusing the source. In fact sometime the only source is *in the question itself!*

What makes a new answer unique and valuable is the explanation of the reference and the conclusions that you can summarize. Clearly, in the example given, adding a new answer would add new valuable content to the site, so feel free to do it.

Comment: Since I already have an answer to the question, I wouldn't be adding a new answer, but I would add the new source to my already existing answer, which cites a different source.

Comment: That's perfectly OK. If you make your answer better, you make the site better.

Comment: I know I have done this, but I can't find it - took a source from an existing answer, and showed it demonstrated the opposite conclusion from the existing answer.